# WERE IN (delete with RETURNING sub-query)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Let's say I have 2 tables.

Table `submissions` with columns: `message_id`, `segment_id`, ...

Table `segments` with columns: `segment_id`, ...

I need to delete records in both tables based on `message_id` only.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
DELETE
    FROM
        segments
    WHERE
        segment_id in (select segment_id FROM submissions WHERE message_id = p_message_id);

DELETE
    FROM
        submissions 
    WHERE
        message_id = p_message_id;
```

But I'm wondering is there more elegant (performance wise) way to do something like this in one go?

```
DELETE
    FROM
        segments
    WHERE
        segment_id in (DELETE FROM submissions WHERE message_id = p_message_id RETURNING segment_id);
```

If I run following 'delete' sub-query for itself, it works properly and it returns deleted segment_id's:

```
DELETE FROM submissions WHERE message_id = p_message_id RETURNING segment_id;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note:  the `RETURNING` clause is available only in MaraDB after 10.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete from two tables at once if you specify them in the `DELETE` clause, so I think you just want something like this:

```
DELETE s, si
FROM segments s INNER JOIN segment_id si
  ON s.message_id = si.message_id
WHERE s.message_id = p_message_id
```

There are [a number of examples here.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/)